# Finding the future position of a non-linear moving object

Tags: javascript, physics, trigonometry

I am trying to predict where a ship will be in within a given amount of seconds, and I thought that I had accomplished this until the turning velocity reaches a high number and turns into a seemingly 3d spiral projected into 2d space, which is what I don't understand.

I've recreated the code with a set of data rendered on a html canvas to demonstrate this (see below)

What am I doing wrong to cause this spiral effect? It looks like it is making a circle, but on the wrong axis.

https://jsfiddle.net/a5d92s1w/7/

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Get a ship's future position in a specified amount of time based on its current velocities
const projectedPosition = (ship, dlta) => {
    const pos = {...ship.position};
    
    // Step through seconds in time and adjust position and angle from each step
    for (let i=0; i < dlta; i++) {
        // Cache current position of ship in time
        const [cx, cy] = [pos.x, pos.y];

        // Add linear velocity to position
        pos.x += ((ship.linearVelocity.x) / 100); 
        pos.y += ((ship.linearVelocity.y) / 100);
        
        // Rotate future direction around current
        const r = (ship.heading + ship.angularVelocity.z * i) * -Math.PI / 180;
        const [cos, sin] = [Math.cos(r), Math.sin(r)];
        pos.x = cx + (cos * (pos.x - cx)) + (sin * (pos.y - cy));
        pos.y = cy + (cos * (pos.y - cy)) - (sin * (pos.x - cx));
    }

    return pos;
}

const draw = () => {
    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 1000;

    const ship = {
        position: {x: 500, y: 100}, // Centre on canvas
        angularVelocity: {z: -8.4}, // The velocity that the ship is turning, in Degrees per second
        heading: 35, // The currently angle the ship is facing, in Degrees
        linearVelocity: {x: 4  * 100, y: -6  * 100} // Metres per second, * 100 for canvas purposes
    };
            
    // Draw Red dot for current ship position
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.arc(ship.position.x, ship.position.y, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
            
    // Draw future positions based on ships velocities
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    for (let i=1; i < 50; i++) {
        const dlta = i * 4; // Every iteration of loops is 4 seconds
        const proj_position = projectedPosition(ship, dlta); 
        
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(proj_position.x, proj_position.y, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
    }
};

draw();
```

Comment: Can you explain how the motion works and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: shouldn't the `ship` position be updated on every iteration of the "future positions" loop?

Comment: @Ry- Currently the boat starts slow and gets to a max speed after some time, turning speed differs based on how fast you are currently going, but usually maxes out at around 10 degrees in either direction while at full speed which is roughly what my test data set has

Comment: @ITgoldman It does, in the form of the pos variable, I don't want to update the actual ship's position since im just doing calculations to work things out for a future time